# How to implement image upload to the PageDown markdown editor?

Tags: ajax, form-data, pagedown

To implement image upload to the PageDown markdown editor, I have modified some code about the editor.

**Markdown.Editor.js**

> var defaultsStrings = { imagedialog : "< input  id='image' type='file' />" }

When select a picture and then click ok button to sent ajax request. It can return image path.

```
var okButton = doc.createElement("input");
        okButton.type = "button";
        okButton.onclick = function () { 
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('file', $( '#image' )[0].files[0] );
            $.ajax({
                url: 'uploadFile',
                data: data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function ( data ) {
                    alert(path);
                }
            });
            return close(false);};
```

**How to preview the image in the editor preview area?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [article](http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/pagedown-markdown-editor-custom-image-dialog) provide a useful method,

```
editor.hooks.set("insertImageDialog", function (callback) {
 var $input = $('<input type="file" name="File" id="file_0" class = "fileUpload"/>');
 var $okButton = $('<a class="okButton">'+uploadOK()+'</a>');
 $okButton.click(function(){
        var data = new FormData();
        var file = $input[0].files[0];
       if (file === undefined || null === file) {
          // alert("error message);
       } else {
         data.append('file',  file);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'uploadFile',
            data: data,
            dataType : 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function ( data ) {
                  callback(data.dataObject.url);
            },
            error : function(data){
                  // error
            }
        });    
      }
    }); )
```

Comment: can you tell me where to include that please ?

Comment: @AmitJoki Include what?

Comment: I want to include it in my project. Could you please provide me the full code ?

Comment: I wrote the above code in another js file. And `var converter2 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();var editor2 = new Markdown.Editor(converter2, '', options);`

Comment: what's that `converter2` ?

Comment: I think that will throw an error like `converter2` is undefined

Comment: also in the last line instead of  `}); )` i think it should be  `})});`

Comment: @AmitJoki  You can find more information [here](http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/pagedown-markdown-editor-custom-image-dialog)